# Проблема с Joomla сайтом

Tags: joomla, php

Добрый день, уважаемые коллеги.
Вопрос вот какой:
Есть сайт на Joomla, сегодня вечером на нем произошел сбой. Сейчас ситуация такая:

1. На главную страницу зайти можно.
2. При попытке перейти с главной на любую второстепенную страницу пишет что искомая страница не найдена.
3. В режиме с отключенным SEO-модом все в порядке. При включении его - опять все страницы кроме главной не находит (404 ошибка).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если включен SEO мод, то файл .htaccess должен быть, и к тому же должен быть не пустым. Как правильно подсказал #owlet нужно взять файл из дистрибутива вашей версии Joomla. Файловый менеджер у таймвеба не показывает файлы которые начинаются с точки(считаются системными). Я лично пользуюсь программой WinSCP для файлового доступа к серверу.

Comment: да да, я уже эту информациб выудил из их администрации. Пробовал загрузить .htaccess из дистрибутива. Оказалось бесполезно. Вместе и админом хостинга проверили все и оказалось что сайт хапнул какой-то вирусняк. и именно он изменил .htaccess сейчас решаем эту проблему с разработчиком сайта. В любом случае спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте посмотреть наличие файла .htaccess в корне сайта. Если он загадочным образом пропал, возьмите его из дистрибутива джумлы (там он [htaccess.txt](http://htaccess.txt), нужно переименовать в .htaccess)

Comment: Мне вчера дали такой же совет. Сказали создать пустой .thaccess и засунуть в корень. так я и сделал. Но (хотинг timeweb) это хостинг работает очень интересно, похоже что он автоматически скрывает .thaccess файлы и поэтому я не вижу его в списке файлов на сервере.  У меня к Вам вопрос, может он должен быть не пустой?

Comment: Ну собственно Fuzzz3r уже ответил, что он должен быть не пустой, только еще момент, у вас тут написано .thaccess - может опечатка, должно быть именно .htaccess
Я FileZilla для доступа к FTP использую, все скрытые файлы отображает